# Vuejs Show Element if Window.print?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, printing

I'm just curious if this is possible to do. I have a button on my page that shows 'Pay Now' that I don't display when a user goes to print the page. I want to display a line of text that shows 'Visit [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to pay now' *ONLY* if the user clicks the print button, and disappears when the user clicks out of the print preview. Is that something I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need vue for this.
You can add the following CSS

```
.print-only {
    display: none;
}
@media print {
    .no-print {
        display: none;
    }
    .print-only {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Using your example

```
<a href="www.example.com" class="print-only">Visit www.example.com to pay now</a>
```